# how to display pdfs in webpage using html in django

Tags: python, html, django, database

how to retreive multiple pdfs from database and display it in webpage using html in django?

this is my function in views.py

```
def PdfView(request):
    pdf = EbookModel.objects.all()
        form=SearchForm()

        context ={
        'pdf':pdf,
        'form':form,
        }
```

here's my html file:

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% block content %}
  {% for pdfs in pdf %}
  <a href="">{{pdfs.title}}</a>
  {% endfor %}

 <form method ='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try  <a href="{{ pdfs.url }}">{{pdfs.title}}</a>

Comment: @yagus it didn't work

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are getting or what happens when you click on the link?

Comment: it works if you made a slight changes in your code,u have to add the variable which is used in models.py holding filefield function <a href="{{pdfs.pdf.url}}">{{pdfs.title}}</a> here pdf is the variable i have used in models.py pdf=models.FileField()